# Overpass API query to retrieve way ids given a list of node ids

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo, nodes

Given a list of node ids returned by [an OSRM map matching query](https://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/driving/8.610048,46.99917;8.620048,46.99917?overview=simplified&generate_hints=false&annotations=nodes&radiuses=50;50&geometries=geojson) I am trying to find a list of corresponding way ids:

> {"nodes":[384845483,3831831361,2628299968,502266756,346268605,373873712,1302513709,9444444740,2431858827,10287564212,271979126,10721097610,10287564276,10721097609,10721097608,7328319500,7328319511,10287564277,271979123,9441944872,271979114,4560271019,373878694,4560271018,373878690,9442435560,373878688,9053978499,9442435552,9442435679,373878684,1085916739,373880925,9442435755,1085916895,373880928,1085916901,373880931,5753185380,373880934,4244175765,2431858826,433073515,373880937]},"distance":927.4}

However in [the Overpass API manual](https://dev.overpass-api.de/overpass-doc/en/criteria/) I can not even find a similar query, that would use any ids.

Is it even possible to search by a node id with the Overpass API or is it only meant to use tags and bounding boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually fairly easy to do:

```
node(id:384845483,3831831361,2628299968,502266756,346268605,373873712,1302513709,9444444740,2431858827,10287564212,271979126,10721097610,10287564276,10721097609,10721097608,7328319500,7328319511,10287564277,271979123,9441944872,271979114,4560271019,373878694,4560271018,373878690,9442435560,373878688,9053978499,9442435552,9442435679,373878684,1085916739,373880925,9442435755,1085916895,373880928,1085916901,373880931,5753185380,373880934,4244175765,2431858826,433073515,373880937);
way(bn);
out geom;
```

Query: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1tPl

You would need to do a bit of post processing on your end to see where each of the nodes ended up. This shouldn't be a big issue, though.

Comment: Thank you, your query is working perfectly and I was expecting having to do the post-processing to match the way nodes... But what is meant by `way(bn)` in the query? Is `bn` some special key word?

Comment: way(bn) gives you the parent ways for nodes in the inputset, and it's documented here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Recurse_(n,_w,_r,_bn,_bw,_br)